# Input combined with a while-loop

Tags: python, input, while-loop

I create a lot of simple functions and programs for myself; this is one of the functions that I like to use a lot because of its simplicity.

```
answer = True

while answer:
    user = input ("name: ")
    if user == "John":
        answer = False
    else:
        print ("who are you ?")
```

The function does everything that I need it to. The while-loop remains until the correct answer is given. As I am still a beginner, I would like to know if this is good coding style or if there is maybe a more elegant way of doing this.

Any comments or tips would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I'd use `while True:` and `break`, per https://refactoring.guru/remove-control-flag, but review of working code is off topic here. Maybe see [codereview.se], but I think this is too trivial a snippet for that site.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the same functionality by trying this:

```
while True:
    user = input ("name: ")
    if user == "John":
        break
    else:
        print ("who are you ?")
```

You can also try this:

```
while True:
    user = input ("name: ")
    if user != "John":
        print ("who are you ?")
    else:
        break
```

In both of these implementations, `while True:` is being used to run an infinite loop and `break` is being used to exit the loop if the specified conditions are fulfilled.

Comment: Ah okay, I knew that both options are possible. I just wasn't sure which options was the best of that is to be decided on a case-by-case basis.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve what you want to do by typing `break` statement, `break` will break the loop and continue.

**Try this:**

```
while True:
    user = input ("name: ")
    if user == "John":
        break
    else:
        print ("who are you ?")
```